# Inter Server Error : php access dynamically created element array

Tags: javascript, php, post

talbe row with as set of elements (textboxes) are dynamically created by Javascript like follow:

```
var newitemstr="<tr id='id_newitemrow_cnt'>"+
                "<td> <input type='checkbox' id='id_item_cnt'></td>" +
                "<td><input type='text' name='itemdesc[]' id='id_itemdesc_cnt' class='offerval'></td>"+
                "<td><input type='text' name='itemquty[]' id='id_itemquty_cnt' class='offerval'></td>"+
                "<td><input type='text' name='itemprice[]' id='id_itemprice_cnt' class='offerval'></td>"+
                "<td><input type='text' name='itemother[]' id='id_itemother_cnt' class='offerval'></td>"+
                "</tr>";

itemcnt = itemcnt + 1;

newitemstr = newitemstr.replace(/cnt/g, String(itemcnt));

//alert(newitemstr);
$("#id_itemtable").append(newitemstr);
```

after submitted, i want to retrieve the values that are input in the dynamically created textboxes using php file like :

`$itemd = $_POST['itemdesc'];
         $itemq = $_POST['itemquty'];
         $itemp = $_POST['itemprice'];
         $itemo = $_POST['itemother'];
$itemd = $_POST['itemdesc'];`

however, i got "Internal Server Error", any suggestion about reasons? thanx in advance.

Comment: We are missing a lot of information. How is the form created? What kind of error do you get (check the logs)? Did you check what actually gets sent to the server when the form is submitted?

Comment: I think fetching the post vars is not the reason for your error.

Answer (score 0):

thanx a lot for reply. 
The problem is that in loop control, i miss "$" before index i.